# What is the difference between these code snippets? Parsing binary data

Tags: c#, asp.net, binaryfiles

I have two bits of code that basically do the same thing in two different ways. The only difference is that with one of them, I am posting a file directly to the asp page and with the other I'm just passing in the location of the file on the server and trying to do the same thing with it. This method works:

```
public static byte[] GetDataFromHttpPostedFile(HttpPostedFile p_oFile)
{
    byte[] oData = new byte[p_oFile.InputStream.Length];
    p_oFile.InputStream.Read(oData, 0, oData.Length);
    return Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oData));
}
```

This snippet does not work. With the same file (`p_oFile` and `fileLocation` refer to the same file)

```
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocation);
    fileData = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData));
```

This is the error message:

A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

But the files are exactly the same... I don't understand how one code snippet correctly converts the file and the other doesn't. What is the difference?

Comment: What is the length of the `InputStream`? And what is the length of `fileData`? If they are not the same, you have a problem.

Comment: `fileData` is byte[3795002] and the `InputStream` is byte[15336] apparently being posted over and over. I am not sure why that would be, I don't have access to the code that passes the file to the working method so I don't know if it's doing some other stuff before the file gets posted. I was told it is not but I Just can't figure out why this would be...

Comment: I guess that is just the size of the read buffer.